# How to add a class to the right navigation element based on a string if Vue.js :class='' takes a boolean?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this simple fixed navigation bar:

```
<nav class='navigation'>
    <div :class="{ active: }" @click='scrollTo(".test1")'></div>
    <div :class="{ active: }" @click='scrollTo(".test2")'></div>
    <div :class="{ active: }" @click='scrollTo(".test3")'></div>
    <div :class="{ active: }" @click='scrollTo(".test4")'></div>
</nav>
```

I also have a property called activeSection:

```
data() {
    return {
        activeSection: test1 // This is either test1, test2, test3 or test4 but let's use test1 for this example
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to apply the class `active` to the first navigation element if `activeSection == test1` or to the second if `activeSection == test2` and so on and so forth but I'm stuck on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is pretty simple

```
<nav class='navigation'>
 <div :class="{ active: activeSection==test1 }" @click='scrollTo(".test1")'> 
 </div>
 <div :class="{ active: activeSection==test2}" @click='scrollTo(".test2")'> 
</div>
<div :class="{ active: activeSection==test3}" @click='scrollTo(".test3")'> 
</div>
<div :class="{ active: activeSection==test4}" @click='scrollTo(".test4")'> 
</div>
</nav>
```

and you need to update value of activeSection on `scrollTo` method as well
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html